# Are static typescript class methods tree shakeable by rollup?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, rollupjs

Suppose we create a typescript class with two static methods:

```
export class Utilities {
      static methodFoo() { return 'foo'}
      static methodBoo() { return 'boo'}
}
```

Later someone imports our class from the npm package `@scope/utilities` and uses only `methodFoo` like this

```
import {Utilities} from '@scope/utilities';

let pityTheFoo = Utilities.methodFoo();
```

If we use rollup to publish the above as an optimized / 'treeshaken' module, will rollup be able to shave off `methodBoo`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As of November 2019, no, static methods aren't treeshaken.
[Rollup Issue #349](https://github.com/rollup/rollup/issues/349) was raised for it, where [even the tool creator was sympathetic to having the feature](https://github.com/rollup/rollup/issues/349#issuecomment-166670563). The issue [closed in an auto-cleanup](https://github.com/rollup/rollup/issues/349#issuecomment-519137342) due to inactivity since.

As for testing the behavior, you can easily do it yourself: just build a class with a static method that's never used, use rollup.js (or angular or something that includes rollup) and examine the output.

I'm struggling myself with this, because how are you then going to build treeshakable utils? Just do it like rxjs and export all functions individually? Then you'll loose all the namespacing, which doesn't seem ideal to me either... I'm guessing your question originated from that thought?

So as far as I know you currently either export plain functions or your utils won't be treeshaken.

Comment: Don't wrap them in the class. Just export them individually as functions.

Comment: I created this typescript library: https://github.com/fireflysemantics/is/blob/master/src/is.ts      Instead of attaching the functions to an `Is` class, they are exported individualy like you are saying, but all methods are prefixed with `is`, so it's essentially the same thing.  We can also use namespace aliases in Typescript in the event that there is an import conflict.

Comment: [This article](https://medium.com/@devongovett/parcel-v1-9-0-tree-shaking-2x-faster-watcher-and-more-87f2e1a70f79) also says that parcel can tree shake commonjs modules.  I assume that means that it might be able to tree shake static methods on a class, since a commonjs export has a similar structure.

Comment: I share your concern with losing namespacing when exporting all functions individually. Of course you can explicitly add imported functions to a class or object to "restore" namespacing but still less than ideal. Any update on your struggle would be much appreciated.

Comment: You can namespace individually exported functions on import like `import * as utilities from './utilities'`